# i get 403 Forbidden error in browser for laravel that uped using docker

Tags: laravel, docker, apache, docker-compose, dockerfile

I get a `403` Forbidden error in browser that i uped Laravel using Docker.

How can i fix this error?

I have two Laravel projects one of them is back-end and another is front-end.

My directory and file structure is this one:

```
my_project/
backend/
frontend/
docker-compose.yml
```

I have two Dockerfiles, inside the `backend/` and `frontend/` directory.

My `docker-compose.yml` it is the next one:

```yaml
    version: '3.8'
 
    services:
      back-end:
    container_name: back-end
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8000:80
 
      front-end:
          container_name: front-end
          build:
            context: ./frontend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
          volumes:
            - ./frontend:/var/www/html/
          ports:
            - 7000:80
 
      db:
        container_name: db
        image: mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: chameleons
          MYSQL_DATABASE: crm
          MYSQL_USER: mohammadreza
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: chameleons
        ports:
          - "9906:3306"
 
      phpmyadmin:
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        environment:
          PMA_HOST: db
          PMA_PORT: 3306
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: chameleons
        ports:
          - 8080:80
        depends_on:
          - db
```

My `Dockerfile` file for each Laravel service:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```